# How to retrieve an object by its name in java

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a game in java with around 7,000 game pieces. Each piece extends a base Object called `Card`. Each piece has a different property(what it can do).

---

I need to be able to load these Objects dynamically by calling their name. So say The user wanted to use a card named "Card no.1" He would type "Card no.1" and it should then create a new "Card_no1" object. How do i go about doing this?

---

I have thought about placing every object in a Hashtable and using its name as the key. Any better ideas?

---

EDIT:
I already have the Card Objects programmed. I am just not sure how to load them. I need to be able to retreive them by using their name, NOT create a new object and name it that. This is because I have to program every individual effect.

Comment: Objects don't *have* names unless you give them to them (e.g. by having a `name` field). If you were thinking about your *variable* names, they're very different. Variables are specified only at compile-time - you can't create a new field at execution-time.

Comment: @jonskeet Thank you, I understood that though, which is why i am stumped as to how to go about doing this. Basically it is supposed to be a very small "yu-gi-oh" like game. But im not used to thinking in terms of OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's a class file for each card, and you want to create a new object when called, then what you want doesn't need to involve hashtables. Do something like this instead (programatically instantiate a class):

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor.*;

String cardName = <whatever>
Card newCard = Class.forName(cardName).getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```

If the game pieces are represented by objects, not class files (i.e. you don't have 7,000 different class files) then each card should have a `name` field. In that case something you might do would be stick them all in a hashmap using their name as the key. Then, when you want to make a new card of a specific type, retrieve its object and call `clone()`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Just curious — do you in fact have 7,000 class files?

Comment: 7000 was just a number. I have around 150 game pieces. And yes, i do have a class file for each one because their effects are all different and have to be hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is this

As user type card no 1, create a new object with a specific property set with value as "Card no1". So once user type some name for card , create a new object

```
 String userInput= req.getParamter("cardSeq");
 Card card1 = new Card();
 card1.setName(userInput)
```

Though answer is very simple but this what i think you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You already know the best way to get a card from pool of 7000 cards HashMap.
Use HashMap instead of HashTable for reasons related to synchronization.

And do remember to override hashCode and equals methods correctly.